# Valueerror invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property of scatter. Tried to plot multiple graphs sharing one x-axis using plotly but failed

Tags: python, plot, plotly, valueerror

I got errors everytime I try to combine graphs together using plotly. I have no problem when it's just x1,y1. But when I try to have x1,x2,.. and so on, it starts giving me the error as mentioned in the title. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
#plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import chart_studio.plotly as py




excel_file = 'C:\\Users\\Taffy R. Mantang\\Desktop\\matrixtester.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(excel_file)
df.head()
data0 = [go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/0'],mode='lines',name='0/0')]
data1 = [go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/1'],mode='lines',name='0/1')]
data2 = [go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/2'],mode='lines',name='0/2')]
data3 = [go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/3'],mode='lines',name='0/3')]

layout = go.Layout(title='processor ISW-1',plot_bgcolor='rgb(230,230,230)',showlegend=True)

fig = go.Figure(data=[data0,data1,data2,data3],layout=layout)

py.offline.plot(fig)
```

When I only plot data0, or data1 and so on, it works. But when I try data = [data0,data1,data2,data3] it gives me the error.

What exactly is the problem? Help :'(((

I used the code from this website:
[https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~notebook_demo/84.embed](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Enotebook_demo/84.embed)

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate traces using the fig.add_trace() command, so this will allow you to create multiple traces of graphs on a single plot. This website should help: https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#adding-traces,

In your instance you could do

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
#plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import chart_studio.plotly as py


excel_file = 'C:\\Users\\Taffy R. Mantang\\Desktop\\matrixtester.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(excel_file)
df.head()
data0 = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/0'],mode='lines',name='0/0')
data1 = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/1'],mode='lines',name='0/1')
data2 = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/2'],mode='lines',name='0/2')
data3 = go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],y=df['0/3'],mode='lines',name='0/3')

layout = go.Layout(title='processor ISW-1',plot_bgcolor='rgb(230,230,230)',showlegend=True)

fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)
fig.add_trace(data0)
fig.add_trace(data1)
fig.add_trace(data2)
fig.add_trace(data3)

plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: py.offline.plot(fig) is not working, so I decided to use plotly.offline.plot(fig), and it seems to work. Just make sure to copy and paste the code, because it seems to work (although I did use my own data).

Comment: Another question I should also ask, what is the error you are getting

Comment: I tried to copy paste it works! :''''''''')))))))

Comment: It likely was because you left the definition of data0 through data4 as a list, which is the incorrect thing to do